# Create and deploy NFT collectibles ERC721 collection with smart contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, metamask, nft, visual-studio-code

I want to start developing with Solidity in my Visual Studio Code my first ERC721 Collectible NFT collection so i installed Visuall Studio Code first, then nodejs and npm and in the end Truffles and Ganache.

-I work on Window 10 OS -Nodejs Version is v14.16.0 -npm Version is 7.6.3 -Solidity v0.5.16

I want my collection to be like cryptokitties project.So the collcetibles can breed.

Can anyone provide me some step by step advice, some links or youtube videos that can help me understand the process in that ? Also except from the code the tools i must use to achieve the result i want. Detailed answers it will make me so happy because i am a beginner on this. Also i want to test it first on testnet.

Thank in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome tutorial available for this. Check out [CryptoZombies](https://cryptozombies.io/) it teaches the basics of ERC721 step by step.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will check it!!